# How to use different attribute on change the second select option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to change the value of my input box by changing two different select options.

The first `select` box is `product_type` with two different data attributes on the options: `data-price` and `data-price_c`.

The second Select box `pay_type` is to selecting between `data-price` or `data-price_c`, to update the value of `lprice`.

This is what I've tried:

```js
var sp = document.getElementById('select_product');
var lp = document.getElementById('lprice');
var count = document.getElementById('count');
var fp = document.getElementById('price');
var pt = document.getElementById('paytype');

var selected_type = pt.options[pt.selectedIndex];

sp.onchange = function(){
    var selected = sp.options[sp.selectedIndex];
    if (selected_type === 1){
        lp.value = selected.getAttribute('data-price');
    } else {
        lp.value = selected.getAttribute('data-price_c');
    }
    fp.value = "";
};
sp.onchange();
count.onchange = function(){
    fp.value = lp.value * count.value;
}
```

```html
                <div>
                    <label for="select_product">Select Product</label>
                    <select name="product_id" id="select_product" onchange="update();">
                        <option value="1" data-price="10000" data-price_c="11000">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="2" data-price="20000" data-price_c="21000">Product 2</option>
                        <option value="3" data-price="30000" data-price_c="31000">Product 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="paytype">Pay type:</label>
                    <select name="paytype" id="paytype">
                        <option value="1">Cash</option>
                        <option value="2">Dept</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="lprice">Single Price:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lprice" id="lprice" class="form-control" tabindex="1" readonly/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="count">Count:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="count" id="count" class="form-control" tabindex="1" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="price">Full Price:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" tabindex="1" readonly/>
                </div>
```

Comment: First of all in your if you need to use == or even better ===, single = in JS is to assign sign. So your if statement wasn't doing anything to start with.

Comment: Also please make HTML with example data so JS can be tasted. Its easier for everyone.  How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and with wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understated you correctly what needs to be done from code and explanation:

Your first problem was that you had your `selected_type` outside of you onchange function so it wasn't getting the changed options onchange.

Second is that you where trying to compare values `1 & 2` with element without actually extracting those values from element (missing `.value` on `selected_type`)

I assumed you will need to update the values on your `Pay type` change too as well as `Select Product`, so there is nit trick to wrap both HTML selects into one div in this case `div id="wrapper"` and that will listen on both selects and call function if any of them are changed. So now you call it on `wrapper.onchange`.

I would also advise to put your calculation  `fp.value = lp.value * count.value;` inside this function to update total price on change of any of those elements so I wrapped your `Count:` into `wrapper div`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var sp = document.getElementById('select_product');
var lp = document.getElementById('lprice');
var count = document.getElementById('count');
var fp = document.getElementById('price');
var pt = document.getElementById('paytype');

var wrapper=document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.onchange = function(){
    var selected = sp.options[sp.selectedIndex];
    var selected_type = pt.options[pt.selectedIndex].value;   
    if (selected_type === "1"){
        lp.value = selected.getAttribute('data-price');
    } 
    if (selected_type === "2"){
        lp.value = selected.getAttribute('data-price_c');
    }
    fp.value = "";
    fp.value = lp.value * count.value;
};
wrapper.onchange();
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
                <div>
                    <label for="select_product">Select Product</label>
                    <select name="product_id" id="select_product" >
                        <option value="1" data-price="10000" data-price_c="11000">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="2" data-price="20000" data-price_c="21000">Product 2</option>
                        <option value="3" data-price="30000" data-price_c="31000">Product 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="paytype">Pay type:</label>
                    <select name="paytype" id="paytype">
                        <option value="1">Cash</option>
                        <option value="2">Dept</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <label for="lprice">Single Price:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lprice" id="lprice" class="form-control" tabindex="1" readonly/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="count">Count:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="count" id="count" class="form-control" tabindex="1" />
                </div>
</div>
                <div>
                    <label for="price">Full Price:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" tabindex="1" readonly/>
                </div>
```